# Select from table where at least two rows are within a value

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table:

```
store || item || value 
----------------------
   x  ||   a  ||  100  
----------------------
   x  ||   b  ||  90    
----------------------
   x  ||   c  ||  100  
----------------------
   y  ||   a  ||  80  
----------------------
   y  ||   b  ||  90   
----------------------
   y  ||   e  ||  100  
----------------------
   z  ||   a  ||  100  
----------------------
   z  ||   b  ||  50  
----------------------
```

I need to select all stores that have at least two items within 10 units of each other.

So for the example table:
x has items a and b, and b and c, and a and c within 10 units.
y has items a and b within 10 units, and b and e within 10 units.
z has no items within 10 units.

So the result would be:
x and y

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.store, t1.item, t1.value
FROM tbl t1
WHERE EXISTS (
   SELECT 1 
   FROM tbl t2
   WHERE t2.store = t1.store
   AND t2.item <> t1.item
   AND t2.value BETWEEN t1.value - 10 AND t1.value + 10
)
```

and/or

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.store, t1.item, t1.value
FROM @t t1
JOIN @t t2 ON t2.store = t1.store
          AND t2.item <> t1.item
          AND t2.value - 10 <= t1.value 
          AND t2.value + 10 >= t1.value
```

Comment: Great. I am actually unfamiliar with the <> syntax. Can you get a quick little description?

Comment: `<>` is "not equal" (ansi compliant), I believe in MySQL you can also do `!=`